# Cannot reconnect the net using regular broadband connection in win732 bit

Tags: windows-7, networking, broadband

I have Windows 7 X32 ultimate.

My internet connection is regular ADSL (broadband).
My problem is that when I disconnect from the internet and then reconnect, everything is fine,
but when I try to reconnect in the 2nd time I get "error 720 a connection to the remote computer..."
It just give me this error again and again no matter what I do - turning off and on the modem, disabling and enabling the connection...

I tried all the command prompt stuff: NETSH, WINSOCK and the like in vain.
Trying to log off, won't help either.

Only restarting the computer will help.

I have ESET smart security 4 (I'm sure it's not the cause, because I disabled it, and the problem still exists).

With win XP (same system, same software) nothing of this happened.

A strange thing is, that sometimes when I get the error, and I close some other program that's running, like PHP designer, the computer suddenly connects successfully.

Thank you for help!

Comment: You disabled it or you uninstalled it?  Why are you using a product that is 3 versions behind the current version?  If your subscription is currently activte you can use the current version.  I am actually HIGHLY suspect of the firewall security because of personal experience with Eset Smart Security myself

Comment: I am using this version because I do not like the new version's interface, and it works fine for me, and if it works, I do not touch. What you say is true, I really just disabled it, do you think it's the cause of the problem?

Comment: I would either uninstall it and verify it still does not work or I would make sure its simply not a bug in the current version.  My personal experience with `ESET Smart Security` while positive overall lead me to stop using it because of the problems with the firewall itself even when its disabled.